# shell grep command to pick only particular string

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file with the following contents

```
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10.xml
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10_log.url
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10_note.xml
```

The numbers may change and are not standard.
And I wish to pick only the 1st one. I am passing all three in to the variable $file. But its showing Version found for all three files. How can I get it only for the 1st

```
if echo "$file" | grep -E "abc_cde_APP"; then
     echo "Version found: $file"
else
 echo "File not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
grep 'abc_cde_app_[^_]*$'
```

it works for your example:

```
kent$  echo "abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10_log.url
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10_note.xml"|grep 'abc_cde_app_[^_]*$'   
abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10
```

Comment: Hi,It worked n,But there is one more file `abc_cde_app_13.5.0.10.xml` Its picking that also. Sorry I didnt mention it before..I will update my question as well

Comment: Try this :`^abc_cde_app_[0-9.]*$`